# Removal of Integration Drift

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, integration, accelerometer

I am integrating acceleration data to get velocity and displacement, but the desired velocity and displacement are not obtained. Raw acceleration data is acquired from accelerometer at 200 Hz sampling frequency. Then DC offset removal is carried out and further filtering is carried out using low pass filter at 5 Hz. After that acceleration is converted into velocity using the formula written below.

```
vx2=0
vy2=0
vz2=0
for n in range (0,int(duration/ts),1):
    Vz2=vz2+(float(Zdiff[n])+float(Zdiff[n-1]))/2*ts
    vz2=Vz2
    Vnz2.append(Vz2)


sx2=0
sy2=0
sz2=0

for n in range (0,int(duration/ts),1):

    Sz2=sz2+(float(Vnz2[n])+float(Vnz2[n-1]))/2*ts
    sz2=Sz2
    Snz2.append(Sz2)
```

Please help me in computing integration drift, so that better estimate of velocity and displacement are generated.

[Acceleration Raw data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byb55RFgILwGQkluV252ZkNfWUE)